# Rails: Sending params to Create method with devise Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to pass in params from user#new to user#create with devise and rails 4, but I can't figure it out. I just want to get @invitation so I can edit it after user is created.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def new
    @invitation = Invitation.find_by_invite_token(params[:invite_token])
    redirect_to root_url if @invitation.nil
    super 
  end

  def create
    @invitation = Invitation.find_by_invite_token(params[:invite_token])

    # Devise create stuff:
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
    if resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        ...
```

**@invitation is nil in user#create**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because #new uses form submit by POST to reach #create, your original GET param will not in url anymore. You can't get the token param in #create without doing something.

The quick fix is to add a field of invitation token in the form. By this you transferred the instance variable `@invitation` in `#new` to a hidden field's value. Of course you can use visible input field as well.

```
#views/devise/registrations/new
<%= form_for(resource..... %>
  <%= f.hidden :invitation_token, value: @invitation_token
```

Then in #create, you get this param within :user

```
def create
  @invitation = Invitation.find_by_invite_token(params[:user][:invite_token])
```

Comment: Your a gentlemen and a scholar. Thank you.